# How to trigger a mail after dataflow job completed to certain dl

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a google cloud dataflow job, triggering at certain time interval. I need to trigger a mail after dataflow job completed with status of the job to certain mail id.

Thanks,
Damodar

Comment: Do you have DataFlow Job ID available (I mean do you have access to it after you schedule your job)?

Comment: No, we dont have job id, since job id is created by google dataflow. Question was, Is there any built in API available for sending mail after job done with status of the job.

Comment: If you're using Python then there's a method that returns DataFlow Job ID once you shedule the job. I'm pretty sure that Java SDK has the same. I don't think that there's a built-in method for sending email, but once you have DataFlow Job ID you could just query DataFlow API in CRON to check the status and send email afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```java
PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();
PipelineResult.State status = result.waitUntilFinish();
// send email
```

You can also include the metrics of the finished job in your email returned by `result.metrics()`.